# java random generator without repeat

Tags: java, random, linked-list, generator

Im trying to generate a 2d array using a random generator.  basically, each column should contain a random value between 1-50 that is not repeated but the problem is, I can't get a repeat value on the same row, or any other row or column in the program.  In other words, each I integer should only display once.  My objects were created via linked list and I will probably integrate the algorthim in there once I figure it out but for now, heres what I did.

```
int[] array = new int[50];



        for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
        {

        int[] grades = new int[5];
            for(int j=0;j<=4;j++)
            {

            int unique = gen.nextInt(50)+1;


            grades[j] = unique; 
            }
            list.add(new Student(i, grades));

        }

        System.out.println(list);
```

My output:

```
Student1: 20 49 45 16 13 
Student2: 28 10 11 30 6 
Student3: 13 25 37 31 49 
Student4: 8 23 8 12 32 
Student5: 22 18 35 2 7 
Student6: 35 8 16 23 36 
Student7: 35 3 15 42 2 
Student8: 43 12 44 2 35 
Student9: 12 21 36 23 12
```

So my issue is this.  How can I implement the random gen without repeating values.  Normally I would try a collection list by now, but I'm trying to do this using java.util.Random  Personally, I would do this a different way but I'm instructed.  Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I would do:

Take an ArrayList of numbers 1-50, then use Collections.shuffle on the list.

Comment: Thats the practical solution but is there a way to implement this using the Random() generator? I'm pretty sure I'm instructed to do it this way.

Comment: @user2188838: Sure, in that case do what vlad-ardelean said.  Collections.shuffle does use a Random generator, btw.

Comment: I'll give it a shot later on today and see if I can do it with collections.  Im waiting on my instructors feedback so the fate of my program depends on what implementation I'll use.  I'll update this thread at a later time to show my results.  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @user2188838 What also may help you is that there's a version of `shuffle` that takes a `Random` as input.  You might want to inform your professor of that.  Regardless of what s/he says, just know that this is probably a good way to implement the answer if you didn't have artificial restrictions placed on you.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the number is unique before accepting it. For example you could try something like the following:

```
int count=0;
List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(count<50){
        int num=random.nextInt(50);
            if(!list.contains(num)){
                list.add(num);
                ++count;  
            }                    
    }
```

Comment: So basically, Make an array list and randomize an integer and check to see if that integer was already used or not.  Then go up each value until I reach 50, right?

Comment: Yes, thats basically what I suggested. Any collection would work, I just suggested a list because it was already mentioned. I would use whatever data-structure your professor suggested you store the results in and if needed (the datastructure doesnt already have it) create a contains method that returns a boolean to check if the number exists.

Comment: The array list implementation I Ended up printing everything in a pattern for each line, so I decided to avoid that way altogether.  I stumbled upon this guide online, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284894/java-random-generator-without-repeat?answertab=active#tab-top

Basically, its suppose to generate the number and add a value that isn't already in place.  the problem with this implementation, is that I keep getting symbol errors despite following everything correctly(specfically on the variables for random and the object.  I rather work on it this way because it seems easier.